# Internet Explorer 8 ignores subsequent link stylesheets

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, comments, conditional-statements

I am using conditional comments to apply different style-sheets for IE. This seems to work fine with IE7, but no matter what I try, I cannot get IE8 to load more than one stylesheet at a time. Both stylesheets appear as options in the Page -> Style menu and I can switch between them but IE8 will NOT apply both at the same time.

Example: http://www.davidapfel.com/booknow.html. I have applied a pink background in IE for testing purposes. IE7 displays the page as I intend it, but IE8 completely ignores the iefix.css and iefix2.css stylesheets. (I tried removing the conditional comments but that made no difference).

Thanks in advance for any clues

**Edit:** Just found that the same problem exists with IE9 - it also ignores the extra stylesheets.

Comment: You want the titles to be the same for every file that is meant to be active together.  So all of your rel="stylesheet" should either have the same title or no title (no title means "apply no matter what other stylesheet is active").

Comment: Yup that solves it - Thanks so much! So it's actually IE7 that was applying it wrongly in my example.